# Globally accessible modal component in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am struggling to find a neat way to implement modals that are accessible from anywhere in my app.

I want to avoid having a local state with `isOpen` in every component that has a modal, since only one modal should be visible at once. I also want to avoid having to send down props to all components since it's uncertain from which components the modal should be able to be activated in the future.

I attempted solving it with Redux, having a base modal component implemented in my top-level `App` component, then storing `isOpen` and `component` in a modal substate in Redux, but this introduced a lot of problems since that component has to be updated every time a user interacts with the modal.

I also made an attempt using React 16's Portals, but it didn't seem to fit my needs. Help appreciated. Any ideas or best practices here?

Comment: Why is the component having to update a problem? Could you elaborate a little more, maybe with a specific example.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Absolutely. One of the modal components included an `input` field, so every time i inputted a character into this field a Redux call had to be made in order to update its `component` state.

Comment: So are you saying that when the input value changes, the component updates and the modal closes?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the implementation of modals in react-semantic-ui, modal is self managed component instantiated through portal in body root. If you want to access it everywhere in your app simplu make a ref to it and pass it down to your compoent three.

Answer (score 0):

What you are already using is centralized state that you implemented with Redux.

Maybe the implementation becomes clearer with React Baobab so that only components are rerendered that should rerender.

Note: For demonstration reasons I'm just working with one property "isOpened" which is not working with a lot of components using the modal. If this is the case you need to add something else into your state, for example an id of the modal that you want to open and check if this id is set (in SomeComponent).

The modal:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="myModal"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

SomeComponent:

```
import React from "react";
import { branch as BaobabBranch } from "baobab-react/higher-order";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { openModal } from "./actions/Modal";

@BaobabBranch({
    modal: ["modal"]
})
export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        modal:    PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    onOpenModal() {
        this.props.dispatch(openModal);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="someComponent">
            { this.props.modal.isOpened ?
                <Modal />
                    :
                <div class="content" onClick={::this.onOpenModal}></div>
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

actions/Modal:

```
export const openModal = state => {
    state.select("modal").set(Object.assign({}, state.get("modal"), {
        isOpened: true
    }));
};
```

state:

```
import Baobab from "baobab";

const state = new Baobab({
    modal: {
        isOpened: false,
        content:  "someContent"
    }
});
```

Now short explanation:

The state holds the global state which is initialized with the values above. By clicking on the content div of SomeComponent the openModal action is executed. The first arg of all actions is always the state itself. As soon as a value of the state is changed all listening components (by using @BaobabBranch) get informed about the new props and rerender.

So if you add another component you can listen to the modal value, too. With that you have everything you need to centralize modal handling and not to bubble values down and up between the layers.